# Django not showing text after extending

Tags: python, html, django

I am learning Django and extended two html files. After extending I am getting the color that I wanted, but no text. My code is below:

**base.html**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="red">
    
    {% block content %}

    {% endblock %}
    
</body>
</html>
```

**home.html**

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block conent %}

<h1>Hello {{name}}!!!!!!!</h1>

{% endblock %}
```

**views.py**

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

def home(request):
    return render(request, 'home.html', {'name': 'Bob'})
```

**Before base.html**

[Before base.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzYMr.jpg)

**After base.html**

[After base.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwFxj.png)

Comment: You have a typo in `home.html`. Instead of `{% block conent %}` it should be `{% block content %}`.

Comment: Added answer without seeing your comment

Answer (score 1):

There's a typo in your `home.html`. Its content, not conent

`{% block content %}`